# Mock-up of existing website using existing assets

Tags: web-development, business

I'm working as a business analyst.

They have an externally facing website that need some changes made to it.

I'd like to demonstrate deign proposals on what the new web page might look like. I do not want a wire framing tool.

I repeat. I do not want a wire framing tool.

What I want to do is make an exact copy the existing web page and insert radio buttons, javascript, change text and styling etc. and have it work.

For example, in my design demonstration meeting I want to click a button I have NEWLY inserted as part of my design idea. Clicking the new button will drive javascript to disable fields or display a message.

I've considered Google's https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/

Any other ideas?

I repeat. I do not want a wire framing tool.

Answer (score 1):

> They have an externally facing website that need some changes made to it.

Those "they" should also have a development environment where they do development of the website before putting it into production. So all you need to do is to work with them in order to get access to one of those environment and do what you need.

Most probabbly it is going to looks like

- WAMP stack
- DB dump
- backend files

And you have a locally running copy of the website to play with.